# How to toggle button's state in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

What I'm trying to do is to enable submit button If all of the textboxes hold values in them. Disable the submit button otherwise. But the problem here is the number of textboxes may vary (dynamic) so I can not hardcode the models in `ng-disabled` attribute.

This is what I've tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/6uKAT/

Is there any other approach I should follow?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is the [basic idea](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Zt2du?p=preview).

```
<form name="myForm">
     Item1: <input ng-model="item1" required/><br/>
     Item2: <input ng-model="item2" required/><br/>
     Item3: <input ng-model="item3" required/><br/>
     <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That's definitely a go but in my case the submit button ($rootScope) does not come under the same controller that of the text-boxes.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, as long as the form wraps all of the inputs you want to look at to disable the submission.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use validation.  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form

Put all the input field with `required` attributes, then any empty input element would
make the form invalid.  If invalid, then disable the button with `ng-disable`.